# jest config hanging when getting coverage

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I have a vue application that has got jest installed as the testing framework. The jest config is in the package.json file. It looks like:

```
"jest": {    
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "js",
  "jsx",
  "json",
  "vue"
],
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
  ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub",
  "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
},
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
},
"snapshotSerializers": [
  "jest-serializer-vue"
],
"testMatch": [
  "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
  "**/tests/unit/**/*.test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
],
"testURL": "http://localhost",
"collectCoverage": true,
"collectCoverageFrom": [      
  "!**/node_modules/**",     
  "**/*.{js,vue}"
],
"coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
"coverageReporters": [
  "html",
  "text-summary"
]
```

}

These are i think the default setting when i installed the vue application using the vue cli.

I am experiencing issues after my tests run the terminal says Running coverage on untested files... and then it just hangs there forever.

If i remove the js bit from `"**/*.{js,vue}"` in the collectCoverageFrom so that it is `"**/*.{vue}"` then the problem doesn't occur and the coverage report completes.

Does anyone have experience of this problem? are there any config settings needed to prevent this issue?

Comment: it looks like it tries to process `node_modules` too. at least that could explain why it freezes. try [`coveragePathIgnorePattern`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#coveragepathignorepatterns-array-string) instead of `"!**/node_modules/**"`. Maybe it's a version-sepcific bug.

Comment: @skyboyer i tried your suggestion and added "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/dist/"  to the coveragePathIgnorePatterns and this seems to do the job.

Comment: your previous comment about specifying `root` looks slightly more correct as for me(since it works)

Comment: ok thanks for that, i'll take another look. I think the coverage % were way out though.

Comment: my mistake, i am using a combination of the two settings and all seems good.